# How to pass FormData with Angular to Laravel action method

Tags: php, angular, laravel, http

I have an existing site built using Laravel. I am "duplicating" the action methods to use Angular, when I duplicated the action that posts a file I didn't get it to work. The $_FILES and $_POST global variables are not being set.

Template: I have an input of type file, when a file is selected I want to send it to the server.

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" [formGroup]="frmUploadFotoUm" (change)="onChange($event)">
    <input type="file"  [formControl]="frmUploadFotoUm.controls['fuUm']"  />
    <progress min="0" value="{{progressStatus}}" max="100"></progress>
  </form>
```

Handler:

```
onChange(event) : void
  {            
      let fileList: FileList = event.target.files;   
      let file: File = fileList[0];   
      let formData: FormData = new FormData();

      formData.append('imagem', file);
      formData.append('imgNum', 1);
      formData.append('imgNome', "testandoAngular");
      formData.append('tipoAnuncio', "venda");
      formData.append('tipoImovel', "casa");
      formData.append('imovelId', 361);
      formData.append('dirAnuncio', 8);

      this.http.post('http://www.example.com/apiuploadfotos/store', formData, {headers: new Headers({ 'Content-Type' : undefined})}
      ).subscribe(res => {});


  }
```

The Laravel action method:

Here I get "not working" all the time.

```
  public function store(Request $request)
{
    if($_FILES)
    {
        echo "working";
        exit();
    }
    else
    {
        echo "not working";
        exit();
    }
 }
```

Comment: why content-type is undefined?

Comment: I changed the headers like 6 times the only option that I didn't touch was Content-Type. I took it now and seems that it worked. When I performed the post with jquery I had to set  the Content-Type to false. I thought it would be necessary.

Comment: You are correct !

Comment: @santoshsingh it worked without the Content-Type. I didn't expect it at all. If you want to post an answer I can set it as the best answer.

Comment: glad it worked :)